# How to find number in an dynamic array c++?

Tags: c++

Say I have an array like this:

```
int* arr;
```

That later gets set to:

```
arr = new int[capacity];
```

How can I check to see if a number is in such an array? I know I can loop through it using a for-loop but is there a function that does this for me?

Comment: [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Comment: `arr` is not an array but a pointer which may or may not point to the first element of an array. It's very bad style and should very likely be replaced with `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
arr = new int[capacity];
const auto end_arr = arr + capacity;
int* found = std::find(arr, end_arr, 42);
if (found == end_arr)
    std::cout << "Not found";
else
    std::cout << "Found at index " << (found - arr);
```

This library function looks for the number between the specified *iterators*, "begin" and "end". In your array, the pointer to the first element is the "begin", while the pointer past the last element (`end_arr`) is the "end".

If the number is not found, the library function returns the end iterator (not `nullptr`, as you might expect), so you have to compare its return value with the end iterator to discover whether the number was found.

---

You can also use `std::vector` to represent an array, instead of "pointer + capacity". This usually leads to easier-to-read code, which is also more robust (i.e. less bugs). `std::vector` holds its capacity internally, and also has dedicated methods `begin` and `end`:

```
std::vector<int> arr;
...
arr.resize(capacity);
...
auto found = std::find(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 42);
if (found == arr.end())
    std::cout << "Not found";
else
    std::cout << "Found at index " << (found - arr.begin());
```

Comment: I'd probably add a `auto const end_arr = arr + capacity` to that. That might increase readability. Or just replace all of this with a `std::vector` and use `begin` and `end`, of course :)